# Long jQuery multiple selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

Right now I have a very long jQuery selector to target many different input fields.

```
$('input[type="text"], input[type="number"], input[type="email"], input[type="tel"], textarea, select', ctx).each(function (){
    // do something
});
```

As you can see, this string is way too long when editing in the text editor, and can only get longer. I wonder if there's a way to better organize it.

I tried breaking it down into different lines like this,

```
$('input[type="text"],   
    input[type="number"], 
    input[type="email"], 
    input[type="tel"], 
    textarea, 
    select', ctx).each(function (){
});
```

but got an error `Unexpected token ILLEGAL`.

Comment: Are you including *types* of inputs? Maybe you just say `input` and then `not` those types which you don't want.

Comment: generally a good idea to add common class to those elements and then only need that class as selector

Comment: @abhitalks there are many other input cases that I need to handle separately, so blanket all of them will not work for me.

Comment: @TriNguyen if you have that many elements, your approach is very hard to maintain. Narrow the selector down by using class. It is the best practice approach

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, consider also:

```
$([
    'input[type="text"]',
    'input[type="number"]',
    'input[type="email"]',
    'input[type="tel"]',
    'textarea',
    'select'
].join(', '), ctx).each( ... );
```

Answer (score 5):

Your string literals are not properly terminated in the line break

```
$('input[type="text"],\
    input[type="number"],\
    input[type="email"],\
    input[type="tel"],\
    textarea,\
    select', ctx).each(function (){
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a jQuery selector for that

```
$(':input', ctx).each(function () {...
```

http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: my thinking also...and add `not` to exclude things like `submit` or `button` if needed

Comment: I could do that, but there are quite a few other form elements that I need to handle separately, so this is not a complete way to handle it, as the `not` selector will be quite long as well.

Comment: And why do you need to handle all these form elements by type? If you have a regular form with firstname, email, phone etc. you should be using names or ID's to target the elements, and not write long selectors that are hard to manage.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I think you can also use backticks ``` (``) ```

```
$(`input[type="text"],
    input[type="number"],
    input[type="email"],
    input[type="tel"],
    textarea,
    select`, ctx).each(function (){
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals